# why Javafx popup font is blur

Tags: java, javafx

On Windows 11 with Java 17 abd JavaFX 17, I'm trying to customize components.

[image: screen capture]

On the left is popup. Font is blurred, This only happens when the displayr is scaled at 125%, and I'm using a 2k display.
And why is the `timeSelector` width on the right different from the popup's? I didn't add extra setting width code. This is strange.

This is minimal reproducible example:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(buildFlowPane());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        Popup popup = new Popup();
        popup.getContent().add(buildFlowPane());
        popup.setAnchorX(600);
        popup.show(primaryStage);
    });
}
private FlowPane buildFlowPane(){
    FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane(){{setStyle("""
                -fx-padding: 2;
                -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 10, 0, 0, 0);
                -fx-background-radius: 5;
                -fx-background-color: white;
                """);}};
    flowPane.setMinWidth(86);
    flowPane.setMaxWidth(86);
    flowPane.setHgap(1.5);
    flowPane.getChildren().add(buildScrollPane());
    flowPane.getChildren().add(buildScrollPane());
    return flowPane;
}
private ScrollPane buildScrollPane(){
    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(){{setStyle("""
            -fx-padding: 0;
            -fx-background-color: transparent;
            -fx-border-color: transparent;
            -fx-background-insets: 0;
            -fx-hbar-policy: never;
            -fx-vbar-policy: never;
            """);}};
    scrollPane.setMaxHeight(180);
    VBox vBox = new VBox(){{setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");}};
    ObservableList<Node> children = vBox.getChildren();
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        children.add(buildLabel(String.valueOf(i)));
    }
    scrollPane.setContent(vBox);
    return scrollPane;
}
private Label buildLabel(String text){
    return new Label(text){{setStyle("-fx-pref-width: 38;-fx-pref-height: 29;-fx-alignment: CENTER;-fx-background-radius: 5;-fx-background-color: white");}};
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the example

[image]

Comment: *" why is the `timeSelector` width on the right different from the popup's"* You made the `timeSelector` the root of the scene, so it is going to be sized to fill the whole scene. The scene is constrained to a minimum size by the window (which needs to be able to hold the window decorations). If you wrap the `timeSelector` in any layout pane, it should have the width specified in the FXML file (note however that it is very bad practice to hard-code sizes in this way).

Comment: @James_D, thanks.

Comment: @jewelsea: Thank you for your advice, but I'm just doing this for the convenience of writing examples

Comment: I tried this on MacBook Pro, OS X x64 13.6, OpenJDK 21.0.1, JavaFX 21.  It did not reproduce.  One pane did not look more blurry than the other to me (could just be my eyesight, but I do see blurriness on the screenshot in your question).  I also tried screenshotting and zooming the screenshot and could not detect any clarity difference.  So perhaps your issue is platform-specific.

Comment: @jewelsea: Is your display scaling 100%?

Comment: No, it is the monitor on the MacBook. Native is 3072x1920.  I run it at 1536x960 which is 2:1, so 4 native pixels to one virtual one.  The output of `System.out.println(Screen.getPrimary())` is `bounds:Rectangle2D [minX=0.0, minY=0.0, maxX=1536.0, maxY=960.0, width=1536.0, height=960.0] visualBounds:Rectangle2D [minX=0.0, minY=25.0, maxX=1536.0, maxY=905.0, width=1536.0, height=880.0] dpi:112.0 outputScale:(2.0,2.0)`.  The [output scale](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Screen.html#getOutputScaleX()) printed last is the scaling.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that the OS specific
implementation does.

The popup is rendered at a given size when using 100%. If you zoom everything to 125% in your OS, you are not resizing the windows only. You are resizing everything to a bigger size.

Imagine a sharp foto of 400x400px. And now you resize it to 500x500px. Where do the 100px come from? They do NOT exist.

This is the much more interesting question. :)

Your computer does the best it can to "compute" this pixels in combination with the JFX implememtation.

What I want to say is: The popup implementation of JFX is the reason OR your OS is the reason.